# How would i search inside a tar file for executable files and use that number as a variable?

Tags: bash

So far i have this:

```
Executables=$(cd $tarchive | awk ‘{print $1 }’ | grep –c ‘d’)
```

This searches for `.sh` files and counts them, in theory. I would like to do the same thing but for executable files.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Executables=`tar -tvf archive.tar | grep "^...x" | awk '{print $6}'`
```

Explanations:

- ``command`` is the same as `$(command)`
- `tar -tvf archive.tar` lists the contents of `archive.tar` in *verbose* mode (necessary to get file permissions)
- `grep "^...x"` gets all lines that start with three symbols (`.` stands for anything), followed by an `x` (meaning that this is an executable file)
- `awk '{print $6}'` prints the 6th column, in this case the filename